# ChangeNotifierProvider inside ListView in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
class EventTimeModel with ChangeNotifier {
  update() {
      notifyListeners();
  }
}

class SingleEvent extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context2) => event.timeModel,
          child: buildEventColumn());
  }
}

class EventList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: events.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  Event event = events[index];
                  return SingleEvent(event: event)
  }
}
```

`EventList` uses a `ListView` to display mutliple SingleEvents. `SingleEvent` uses a `ChangeNotifierProvider` to provide `EventTimeModel`. When scrolling up and down I got the message

`Unhandled Exception: A EventTimeModel was used after being disposed.
E/flutter (10215): Once you have called dispose() on a EventTimeModel, it can no longer be used.`

So I think an event was deleted because it has been outside the screen. When it should be displayed again the error was thrown. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `timeModel` exists the create method can't be used here.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: event.timeModel,
          child: buildEventColumn());
  }
```